# SQL Instance object explorer hangs

Tags: sql-server, ssms, instance

we have two instance where while trying to connect to server connection in object explorer hangs

[image]

Tried to restart the server , but issue constantly happening , can not open databases list or something in object explorer. What can be an issue ?

Comment: Restart your computer.

Comment: Already done this few times ((

Comment: Is this SQL Express? Do you have a bunch of databases in auto close? Or one or more databases on a thumb drive or spinning rust?

Comment: Might you have some *significant* latency/bandwidth issues between your machine and the SQL Instance's Host?

Comment: Yes if you are accessing a remote SQL Server, I am curious if you see the same if you RDP and use SSMS _on the server_. If you wait 5 minutes for a click to register inside your RDP session, I think you have your answer. If you have 60,000 databases and it's also slow on the server, I think you have a different answer.

Comment: SQL enterprice , no autoclose , no big count of dbs , i can waiting for hours and this does not show anything

Comment: well, sounds like you are getting blocked then. Same result if you RDP to the server and run SSMS there? What version of SQL Server? What version of SSMS?

Comment: No blockings was there , sometimes im getting error "semaphore timeout expired' . Note that i'm getting this error when trying to connect to SQL server which local installed , this means that I'm logged to server "A" which has SQL installed 
 instance "A"  and I can not to login to server sometimes , I have all required rights.

Comment: 32-bit version of Windows? How big are your databases? How much memory on the box? What is max server memory for SQL Server? Have you considered a newer version than SQL Server 2014, one that is supported maybe?

Comment: Process 0:0:0 (0x1864) Worker 0x00000000037D4160 appears to be non-yielding on Scheduler 17. Thread creation time: 13245520363649. Approx Thread CPU Used: kernel 78 ms, user 3849640 ms. Process Utilization 32%%. System Idle 67%%. Interval: 5078239 ms.

Im constantly see this error in event viewr for MSSQL server service

I have 64 bit version of Windows  66 databases , 4TB overall size